# Position (index) of row in MySQL database with same values

Tags: mysql

I need to get position of player found by column ssid, now I'm using this query

```
SELECT Count(*) + 1 AS pos 
FROM user_data
WHERE honor > (
    SELECT honor 
    FROM user_data 
    WHERE ssid = ''
)
```

but this isn't working on players with same honor, so I need to order it first by honor, second by lvl and if it's still same pos by user_name.

I don't know how to do that, so thanks for all answers.

Comment: Add ORDER BY honor,level?

Comment: still same, I've tried it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT pos, honor, lvl, user_name
FROM (
SELECT honor, lvl, user_name, @r:=@r+1 as pos
FROM user_data, (select @r:=0) r0
WHERE ss_id=''
ORDER BY honor, lvl, user_name) user_data_ordered;
```

The example on SQL Fillde - I had to guess the data types, but it should not be relevant for this query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e69b8a/1

Comment: aah sorry (ssid changed and I used old one) :) but it's still shows same first pos with same values

Comment: Strange. It seems to work with the mock-up data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e69b8a/1